# 11 weeks and concern of THC in babys system at birth

Tags: health, pregnancy, drugs

I was a heavy weed smoker for the past 3 years, up until I found out I'm pregnant. I've completely stopped smoking now. So far, it's been 30 days and I'm 11 weeks pregnant but I recently took a drug test and it still came out positive. My concern is even if I've completely stopped smoking will my baby test positive for [THC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahydrocannabinol) at birth?

Answer (score 2):

Please share this concern with your Ob-gyn. From articles I have read by googling **marijauna and pregnancy**, there are differing opinions. I think that you have stopped is good. Please try not start again.  No smoking  of any substance is good for you or your baby. I cannot make my phone do the link thing at the moment.